# When I compile my code to HTML5 it doesn't always take on the new changes

Tags: libgdx

I've tried gradlew html:clean and then gradlew html:dist
however, it never uses the newest code. It will continue to grab the code from somewhere else and compile older versions of it. I got it to use the newest code once but I am not sure what I did to get it to do that. I'm not sure what files to post here to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For development, there are two ways possible:

- If you don't need to debug and did not already compile: Use html:clean and html:superdev and make sure to delete the browser cache => You will get a fresh version of your game
- If you need to debug or the game is already running: Use html:superdev if you did not already, head to localhost:8080/html, click the button to enter superdev mode (at the upper left corner) and hit recompile => You will get a fresh version of your game ready for debugging

#### For releasing an update of your game:

You need to enforce that all users get a fresh copy of your game. You cannot rely on all users deleting their browser cache, therefore you need to use other tricks for that (changing the directory of the game for every build, using HTTP headers...). I recommend you to use game hosting sites like GameJolt ot itch.io. They do this magic for you, and are trusted sites by players.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer was to Shift-F5 to hard refresh the page. Chrome was caching the old info.